# Marshal's [In] [Out] Attributes

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I'm invoking an unmanaged function in my C# code.

The declaration of this function is as follow:

```
int myFun(unsigned char* inputBuffer, unsigned char* &outputBuffer);
```

I use this function as follow:

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int myFun([In] byte[] inputBuffer, out IntPtr outputBuffer);

byte[] a = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sampletext!");
IntPtr b;
res = myFun(a, out b);
```

Although I mentioned `[InAttribute]` for `byte[] inputBuffer`, the function still changeds the values of `a`. It seems that CLR is using its own default marshaling behavior.
I used `byte[]` because it is C# equivalent for `unsigned char*`.

When I substitite `byte[]` with `char[]` the CLR will follow my In-Out attributes.

I highly appreciate your help.
For more information please read this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx).

Comment: Perhaps `MarshalAs` is what you're looking for?

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller only copies the data when it has to.  It doesn't have to with byte[], it just pins the array and passes a pointer to first element.  So the native code is partying directly on the managed array.  Very efficient.  Different for char[], the elements have to be converted from a 16-bit value to an 8-bit value.  You'll get Encoding.Default values.  The pinvoke marshaller *must* copy, it will not copy back without [Out].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx), with my emphasis:

> As an optimization, **arrays of blittable types and classes that contain only blittable members are pinned instead of copied during marshaling**. These types can appear to be marshaled as In/Out parameters when the caller and callee are in the same apartment. However, these types are actually marshaled as In parameters, and you must apply the InAttribute and OutAttribute attributes if you want to marshal the argument as an In/Out parameter.

Since `byte` is blittable, your array of byte is pinned rather than copied, and so marshals as In/Out.

> When I substitute byte[] with char[] the CLR will follow my In-Out attributes.

The C# type `char` is [not blittable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx). An array of `char` is not pinned, and so `[In] char[]` marshals as an In parameter.

Comment: *The C# type char is not blittable.* what if he used Charset Unicode?

Comment: @xanatos The doc link in my answer lists `System.Char` as non-blittable

Comment: @David Heffernan, many thanks for your answer. This article is useful as well.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23acw07k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Today I finally did a test... If I use `CharSet.Unicode` and I have a `char[]` parameter then the array seems to be simply pinned (the memory address inside the C method is the same as the address outside the C method, and `[In]`/`[Out]` are "implicit")

Comment: @xanatos OK, that seems reasonable. In the code in the question though, `byte[]` is correct since this is binary data.